# Simulating patch-like merging in go structs read from yaml files

Tags: go, merge, yaml, patch

Given the yamls like below:

**default.yaml**:

```
services:
  A:
    host: "google.com"
    path: "search"
    scheme: "https"
  B:
    host: "bing.com"
    path: "find"
logging:
  level: WARN
```

**staging.yaml**:

```
services:
  A:
    path: "search2"
```

I want this merged yaml:

```
services:
  A:
    host: "google.com"
    path: "search2"
    scheme: "https"
  B:
    host: "bing.com"
    path: "find"
logging:
  level: WARN
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of merge/patch behavior in go? I'm playing around with `mergo`, but currently, it converts `services["A"].host` and `services["A"].scheme` to `nil` or `""` in the merged object representation depending on whether the corresponding struct field is a value or pointer.

```golang
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "path"

    "github.com/imdario/mergo"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Logging struct {
    Level *string `json:"level,omitempty" yaml:"level,omitempty"`
}

type Service struct {
    Host     *string `json:"host,omitempty" yaml:"host,omitempty"`
    Path     *string `json:"path,omitempty" yaml:"path,omitempty"`
    Scheme   *string `json:"scheme,omitempty" yaml:"scheme,omitempty"`
    Schedule *string `json:"schedule,omitempty" yaml:"schedule,omitempty"`
    Count    *int    `json:"count,omitempty" yaml:"count,omitempty"`
}

type Config struct {
    Services map[string]Service `json:"services,omitempty" yaml:"services,omitempty"`
    Logging  *Logging           `json:"logging,omitempty" yaml:"logging,omitempty"`
}

// error handling omitted for brevity
func main() {
    var defc Config
    yamlFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("default.yaml"))
    _ = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &defc)

    var envc Config
    yamlFile, _ = ioutil.ReadFile("staging.yaml"))
    _ = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &envc)

    _ = mergo.Merge(&defc, envc, mergo.WithOverride)
}
```

The motivation is to maintain env-specific yaml files that contain various configuration. I want to keep a base yaml (`default.yaml`) that defines all the configuration, and then for each environment (dev/staging/prod...) define only the *delta* in those yamls to keep things DRY.

To give an equivalent from js/node, this is roughly what I'm looking for: https://runkit.com/embed/j9xi2bu00a74

Comment: This can much easier be done with JSON, as it is a much simpler format than YAML (which has tags, anchor/alias, comments that need to be preserved). The only YAML library that can do that that I know of is my `ruamel.yaml`, but that is in Python. Would that be OK for such a pre-process step?

Comment: Did you tried to reverse how you are merging the files? I mean `mergo.Merge(&envc, defc)`? I think that this way mergo should preserve already declared values in you eg. `stage.yml` and just fill up with this existing in `default.yml`

Comment: @ttomalak reversing didn't help either, with or without override.